# Hide ScriptError dialog in WPF WebBrowser

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

It would appear that Twitter now has some Javascript files in their authorization pages that throw some errors on the WPF WebBrowser control.  Is there any way to hide these dialogs?  They are really annoying and make it look like it's the applications error.

This is the error I'm talking about:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same issue when using the WPF Browser Control.  I found the answer here: http://chironexsoftware.com/blog/?p=37, and it has worked perfectly for me.